# RSPEC failure with get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is the failed rspec code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MainMenuController do

  describe "GET 'first_page'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'first_page'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

Here is the controller code:

```
class MainMenuController < ApplicationController
  def first_page
    session[:page_step] = 1
    redirect_to session[:page1]
  end

end
```

The spec error is:

```
 MainMenuController GET 'first_page' should be successful
     Failure/Error: response.should be_success
       expected success? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/main_menu_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The app runs fine without problem and the error may be caused by the rspec code which is automatically generated by the rails. Any idea about the problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the matcher is looking for a status 200.

But since you redirect, it gets 301.

Thus it fails.

Try:

```
response.status.should eq 301
```

You'd have some more details.

Comment: It actually returns 302. Thanks.